# Автозапуск sendmail при перезагрузке

Tags: linux

Как настроить, чтобы при перезагрузке сервака - автоматом стартовал сендмейл и не надо было запускать вручную

```
/etc/init.d/sendmail start
```

П.С. Дистриб Red Hat 4.1.2-42

Answer (score 1):

```
chkconfig sendmail on
```

Answer (score 0):

Посмотри тут не плохо написано:http://forum.try-catch.ru/index.php?topic=379.0

или

http://bookpro.org.ua/linux/avtozagruzka-v-linux.html

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю RedHat, но предположу, что можно покопаться в /etc/rc.local или /etc/rc.conf (но второй вариант вряд ли)Возможно, у redhat есть свои утилиты, но для запуска демонов (сервисов, служб - вы какой религии придерживаетесь?) принято прописывать по указанному пути.

Answer (score 0):

В ком.строке setup пишешь, в открывшемся окне - Системные службы, находишь sendmail и пробелом ставишь звездочку